# How to run the Visual Studio setup project from Command Line

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, setup-project

I have created a Setup Project. I have added a launch condition also. If the condition is not fulfilled it throws me an error. 
Now I want to run the msi file from the command line. But when i do this if there any error (if prerequisite not satisfies) then i need the error also to be listed in the command prompt. Currently when i run it from command prompt the error pops up as a message box. Let me know how i can get this on a command prompt. Or maybe write into a log file and shoe the log file path in the command line.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's nothing to do with development or building an MSI file. It's an IT question.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `MSI` it uses [msiexec.exe](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html), which is *windows-like* application. There is no console for you to write errors into.

Instead you can [enable logging](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-log.html):

> msiexec /i "C:\MyPackage\Example.msi" /L*V "C:\log\example.log"